# Conditional fomatting based on date and whether cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba, date, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

Need some help with a spreadsheet that i have created as a timesheet rota. Basically i would like to highlight cells in the below calendar where the date is less than today and the cell is blank to identify when people have not entered the shift they have worked.

For example on the calendar i would like the top three rows where nothing has been submitted to highlight red

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the worksheet module and adjust the range to suit what you need. Change this `Range("A1:C10")` to suit the ranges that you want affected.

The code will determin if the cell is empty or has a date before today and change the color to red.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)       
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target Is Nothing Then
               Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ElseIf Target <= Date Then
               Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to take into consideration the date on the calendar. It needs to check the date on the black row and see if that is before todays date, and there is a blank cell below it? does that make sense?

Comment: So the row in black is the days of the month in question? How are those numbers entered? Are they dates themselves or are they just integers?

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditonal formating. You have to do the following for every month.

Select a cell (for example E10). Goto [**Condional Formating (on the Home tab) >> Highlight Cells Rules >> more Rules >> Use a formula to....**].

Type

```
=AND(E$5<TODAY(),E10="")
```

in the textbox and choose a format (like highlighting red).

Then apply this formatting to all the cells in that particular month (**Conditional Formatting >> Manage Rules**)

Repeat this proces for the other months.

Comment: That doesnt seem to take into consideration the date on the calendar. It needs to check the date on the black row and see if that is before todays date, and there is a blank cell below it? does that make sense?

Comment: @user2942642 Now I understand what you want. See my updated answer.